# Reading textFile and saving the info into an array C#

Tags: c#

Good morning

I would like to enquire as to how to read a list from a text file and to save the info into a list(array) with c#.

Its a little exercise where I wrote the info to a text file and now I want to read the info and save it into a different array.

```
string name;
        string selection;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:/Documents and Settings/Arian/Desktop/Perl (PERLC-09)/bookExamples/unitThree/menuLunch.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs);
        fs.Close();

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:/Documents and Settings/Arian/Desktop/Perl (PERLC-09)/bookExamples/unitThree/menuLunch.txt");
        Console.WriteLine("writing the menu");

        string[]menu = new string[]{"burger", "steak", "sandwich", "apple", "soup", "pasta", "pizza"};
        for (int i = 0; i < menu.Length; i++)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(menu[i]);
        }

        sw.Close();

        Console.WriteLine("Thanks for creating the menu, could you please tell me your name? ");

        name = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("hallo " + name + " Please make your selection from the menu");

        FileStream fsream = new FileStream("C:/Documents and Settings/Arian/Desktop/Perl (PERLC-09)/bookExamples/unitThree/menuLunch.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BufferedStream bstream = new BufferedStream(fsream);
        fsream.Close();

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:/Documents and Settings/Arian/Desktop/Perl (PERLC-09)/bookExamples/unitThree/menuLunch.txt");


        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
        }

        selection = Console.ReadLine();
```

regards

Comment: start using the `using` keyword: `using(var fs = new FileStream(...)) { ... }`, read something about the disposable pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try like this... it will stores the file contents in array  when the form loads

```
  private ArrayList statusArray = new ArrayList();

private void btnCompleted_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    for (int i = 0; i < statusArray.Count; i++)
    {
        if (statusArray[i].Equals("Complete"))

            lstReports.Items.Add(statusArray[i-2]);

    }
}

private void Reports_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // declare variables
    string inValue;
    string data;

    inFile = new StreamReader("percent.txt");

    // Read each line from the text file

    while ((inValue = inFile.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        data = Convert.ToString(inValue);
        statusArray.Add(inValue);

    }

    // Close the text file
    inFile.Close();


}
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is pretty simple. `File` class comes in with two handy methods that help you to read and write lines from/to a file:

```
// Write
string path = "example.txt";
string[] myMenu = { "A", "B", "C" };
File.WriteAllLines(path, myMenu);

// Read
string[] readMenu = File.ReadAllLines(path);
```