# Saving answers in textfile

Tags: c#, .net, io

Is there a way to 'save' userdata in textfiles (.txt) and re-use them? I'm programming in C#  Visual Studio 2013 (WFA)
Databases/XML files are not allowed!

For example, I program a quiz with several questions. When I start the quiz and give some correct and false answers, I need to be able to save my answers, see my correct/false answers and I have to be able to retry my false answers.

Comment: Yes, it is certainly possible. Have you tried anything? Learned about working with files?

Comment: Typing in google `c# text files` is surely much more faster way to get answers, than typing this question here.

Comment: What Sinatr said is true, although i am inclined to believe that you did not know what to type, and the correct thing, based on your question, is called a streamreader and stream writer, there are tons of tutorials and examples on the web, but please do comment if you find yourself having difficulty along the way. i will assist you, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes. The long answer isn't too bad either. Let's say we structure a set of classes like this:

```
public class Quiz
{
    public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }

    public Quiz() { Questions = new List<Question>(); }
}

public class Question
{
    public string Question { get; set; }

    public bool Answer { get; set; }
}
```

Now let's say the UI builds a nice collection of questions for a quiz and over time sets the answer to true or false, yes or no have you, and so at the end we need to save it:

```
File.WriteAllText(path, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(quiz));
```

This will save the entire quiz and questions in a JSON format to a file path.

Now we need to reload; this is why I used JSON:

```
var quiz = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Quiz>(File.ReadAllText(path));
```

After updates have been made to the object (i.e. answers changed) you can run this again:

```
File.WriteAllText(path, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(quiz));
```

**NOTE:** clearly (or it should be clear) each quiz will need its own file.

**NOTE:** this will also require that you get the [Json.NET NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/), which can be installed with the [NuGet Visual Studio Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c).

Answer (score 1):

There are many many examples of how to do this online and im sure plenty on stack overflow as well.

To Read from a .txt file check this out

[Reading textFile and saving the info into an array C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865562/reading-textfile-and-saving-the-info-into-an-array-c-sharp?rq=1)

To Write to a text file, check this out

[Saving from List<T> to txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883483/saving-from-listt-to-txt?rq=1)